# 3rd visa application

Tags: study, poland, schengen-visas, nigerian-citizens

I am a Nigerian. I will be visiting Germany in August on a tourist visa. Would I be able to get apply for a study visa for Poland as a tourist while in Germany or Austria or any Schengen country? Applying from my home country is a bit unfavorable.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, are you asking if there's a better chance of success if you apply from Germany than from Nigeria? I think success rate depends more on your nationality than the place from where you do it.

Comment: Hello TFAG, for long-term stays you should ask on Expatriates.SE, not on Travel.SE. It is also likely that the Polish officials will inquire into your residency status at the place you apply from.

Comment: What if I go to Poland before studying on a tourist visa, and do it there  will it work that way, the chances of getting a visa in my home country is very slim

Comment: The chances will not get better based on the location you are currently in because that is unimportant compared to what country you are a resident of. Your home country is still your home country. Unless you are thinking it is unfavorable because of the people/ the buerocracy you will have to deal with at home. Still: It will only make it way harder, as you might not be able to easily provide the required documents.

Answer (score 1):

It may prove difficult to apply for a visa to study in Poland, as the Consulates in both Germany and Austria generally accept applications from those who reside there. They may not let an individual to apply who is in the country on a tourist visa, and prior refusals may make it less likely, although exceptions can occur.

The [Polish Consulate in Berlin](http://www.berlin.msz.gov.pl/pl/konsulat3/sprawy_wizowe/) notes that:

> Application is considered by the consulate in whose jurisdiction legally living person applying for a visa. Consulate examine the application filed by the person who legally resides, but not residing in the jurisdiction of the consulate only if the person applying for a visa in detail, written justification for lodging the application at the consulate.

The [Consulate in Austria](http://www.wieden.msz.gov.pl/pl/informacje_konsularne/wizy/;jsessionid=C59FE2B4FBF524190CAF4184984AB606.cmsap1p) has a similar stipulation:

> [V]isa application should be lodged with the competent territorial consular office, adoption of the proposal in another office needs to be justified by the applicant.

The application requirements remain the same as when done within [your home country](http://www.abudza.msz.gov.pl/en/consular_information/visas/), from registering for a visa appointment at www.e-konsulat.gov.pl to the additional documentation for a study visa (e.g., acceptance letter, confirmation of payment of fees, accommodation confirmation, proof of funds etc.).

Comment: Are you saying that it's very possible in Austria or in any other  schengen or non schengen countries apart from Germany in Europe

Comment: @TFAG no, the opposite, that trying to apply for a visa when you don't  reside/live in the country means the consulate may not even consider your application, and would tell you to apply in your home country. There are exceptions, yes, but there has to be a VERY good reason, and saying that doing it in Nigeria is unfavorable probably won't work.